# Markerless AR lib for iPhone

Tags: ios, image-processing, augmented-reality, edge-detection

I'm searching a functional AR Markerless library for the iPhone (from 3GS and supporting iOS 4.3 at least).

I've already tested a large amount of SDKs including Qualcomm AR, Layar, ARToolkit, but none of them was satisfying my needs.

To be more precise, I need neither a localization-based AR technology (Layar), nor a marker technology (ARToolkit).
If possible, the library has to be free, as I don't have much financial resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualcomm ( QCAR ) has recently released an iOS version into beta. So if that's why it didn't meet your needs, it may now.

Also Junaio's Glue provides a simple 'markerless' solution - http://www.junaio.com/publisher/junaioglue

There are also free, and inexpensive, licenses for String - http://www.poweredbystring.com/ but String targets need to have a high contrast rectangular border.

Other SDKs by Total Immersion and Metaio are rather expensive - or they were the last time I'd checked.

If QCAR for iOS will work, that may be your best bet.

Comment: String is at least 485€ per app per year, which is too expensive for me (I'm just a student, don't have so much money)
QCar works only on iPhone 4, which doesn't meet my requirements :(
I'm gonna check the other links, thanks^^

Comment: Have you checked out Aurasma? - http://www.aurasma.com . I haven't worked with their SDK, but it looks like it's free. They have some sort of residual scheme as part of their licensing, which may require that you allow ad placements. It's hard to make out what they require. But they may be worth investigating.