# Best way to create an ios app with AR supports

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markerless AR lib for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953365/markerless-ar-lib-for-iphone)

i have planned to create an iPhone application which support augmented reality with real world objects. 
ex - : Just assume if i hold my camera in front of a bottle and displays a dynamic object next to it. 
The thing is. the object should display only when the app pointing to that bottle.

I have used String framework. But i don't think it can interact with real world things, i think it only interact with images and draw dynamic content upon that.

Is thr any way to fill my requirment

Thanks

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i already test this app. it doesn't recognize the particular objects. that space ship displays every where.